# ajax get data request url not found but already exist, Laravel 8

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, routes

hello guys i have a problem with my ajax data json, i have a project about scan a barcode with a webcam but it just views the code of the barcode, the data in the database not call in my ajax, this is the code of blade, i'm using a modal
this is the modal

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="scanModalLabel">Scan Barcode</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close close-btn" data-dismiss="myModal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            <dl class="row">
                <dt class="col-sm-4"><h4>Kode Barang</h4></dt>
                <dd class="col-sm-8" id="kode_barang"></dd>
            </dl> <hr>
                    <table class="table align-items-center tabel-detail" >
                        <thead class="thead-light">
                          <tr>
                            <th>Nama Barang</th>
                            <th>Harga Jual</th>
                            <th>Stok</th>
                            <th>Insert</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody class="list">
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is the jquery code

```
var args = {
        autoBrightnessValue: 100,
        resultFunction: function(res) {
            [].forEach.call(scannerLaser, function(el) {
                $(el).fadeOut(300, function() {
                    $(el).fadeIn(300);
                });
            });
            scannedImg.attr("src", res.imgData);
            scannedQR.text(res.format + ": " + res.code);
            console.log(res.code);
            document.getElementsByName('qrcode')[0].value = res.code;
            var kode= res.code;
            $('#kode_barang').text(': '+kode);
            $.ajax({
                url:"{{ route('daftar_produk.scan') }}",
                method:'GET',
                data:{kode:kode},
                dataType:'json',
                success:function(data)
                  {
                    $('.list').html(data.table_data)
                  }
              });
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        },
```

this is the controller

```
public function cekScan(Request $req)
    {
        $id = $req->get('kode');
        $output='';
        $produk = Produk::findOrFail($id)
        ->where('kode_barang', '=', $id)
        ->select('produks.*')
        ->first();

        $no = 0;
        $data = array();
        foreach ($produk as $list) {
            $no ++;
            $output .= '<tr><td>'.$no.'</td><td>'.$list->nama_barang.'</td><td>'."Rp.".format_uang($list->harga_jual).'</td><td>'.$list->stok.'</td><td><a type="button" data-stok=(('.$list->stok.')) data-id=(('.$list->id.')) data-nama=(('.$list->nama_barang.')) data-kode=(('.$list->kode_barang.')) data-harga=(('.$list->harga_jual.')) class="btn btn-primary btn-pilih" role="button">Insert</a></td></tr>';
        }
        $data = array(
            'table_data' =>  $output
        );
        return json_encode($data);
    }
```

this is the route

```
 Route::get('transaksi/scan', '\App\Http\Controllers\ProdukController@cekScan')->name('daftar_produk.scan');
```

what should i do the error said "jquery.min.js:2 GET http://localhost:8080/rezkastore1/%7B%7B%20route('daftar_produk.scan')%20%7D%7D?kode=2135758676 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: is js in an external js file??

Comment: yes in external js file

Comment: you can't use blade syntax in a js file. use relative or full url in js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea wether you write your Javascript section, in Laravel Blade View or in separate JS file. If you write it within Laravel Blade Template, you may use

```
    $.ajax({
        url:"{{ route('daftar_produk.scan') }}",
```

but I recommend you to write complete URL within your AJAX call. Make your AJAX call like this :

```
$.ajax({
    url:"/transaksi/scan",
    method:'GET',
    data:{kode:kode},
    dataType:'json',
    success:function(data) {
        $('.list').html(data.table_data)
    }
});
```

Instead of using `findOrFail()`, you can use `find()` or regular `where()` with error handler, because `findOrFail()` will returns `404 not found` if it can't find any records, here is the `cekScan` function

```
public function cekScan(Request $req)
{
    $id = $req->get('kode');
    $output='';
    $produk = Produk::where('kode_barang', '=', $id)->first();

    if (!$produk) {
        return json_encode(['table_data' => 'Barang Tidak Ditemukan']);
    }

    $no = 0;
    $data = array();
    foreach ($produk as $list) {
        $no ++;
        $output .= '<tr><td>'.$no.'</td><td>'.$list->nama_barang.'</td><td>'."Rp.".format_uang($list->harga_jual).'</td><td>'.$list->stok.'</td><td><a type="button" data-stok=(('.$list->stok.')) data-id=(('.$list->id.')) data-nama=(('.$list->nama_barang.')) data-kode=(('.$list->kode_barang.')) data-harga=(('.$list->harga_jual.')) class="btn btn-primary btn-pilih" role="button">Insert</a></td></tr>';
    }
    $data = array(
        'table_data' =>  $output
    );
    return json_encode($data);
}
```

Maturnuwun

Comment: yes i have trying url code with this url:"/transaksi/scan",
but the error said jquery.min.js:2 GET http://localhost:8080/transaksi/scan/?kode=2135758676 404 (Not Found)
have i wrong with my routes code ?

Comment: What is your root URL? `http://localhost:8080/rezkastore1` or `http://localhost:8080` ?

Comment: i'm using this http://localhost:8080/rezkastore1/transaksi/scan/

Comment: Try to add
`<script> var ajaxUrlScan = "{{ route('daftar_produk.scan') }}";</script>` within `<head>` section and change url in your AJAX to :
`url:ajaxUrlScan,`

Comment: i have change the url in ajax and make a global variable route in blade, but the error still say jGET localhost:8080/rezkastore1/transaksi/scan?kode=2135758676 404 (Not Found), have i wrong in controller code ?

Comment: I think it is caused by `findOrFail()` , it will return 404 if your Controller couldn't find kode `2135758676`. Is `2135758676` exists in field `id` or `kode_barang` field?

**1.** Please check if 2135758676 is exists in table `produks`
**2.** I provide you 2 options in your controller `$produk = Produk::find($id);` or `$produk = Produk::where('kode_barang', '=', $id)->first();` 
**3.** use `find()` instead of  `findOrFail()` and _create a handler_ if your Product with ID `2135758676` does not exist e.g `if (!$product) {return json_encode(['table_data' => 'Produk Tidak Ditemukan']);}`;

Answer (score 1):

Seems like problem with URL.

You can't access the route in JS file.

Make a global variable in blade for ajaxURL then use in JavaScript.

```
<script>
var ajaxURL = '{{ route('daftar_produk.scan') }}';
</script>
<script src="xyz.js"></script>
```

Comment: and how to call var of ajaxURL in js file?

Comment: $.ajax({
                url: ajaxURL,
                method:'GET',
                data:{kode:kode},
                dataType:'json',
                success:function(data)
                  {
                    $('.list').html(data.table_data)
                  }
});

Comment: use a global variable ajaxURL instead of route.

Comment: i have change the url in ajax and make a global variable route in blade, but the error still say jGET http://localhost:8080/rezkastore1/transaksi/scan?kode=2135758676 404 (Not Found), have i wrong in controller code ?